# Compute a distance matrix in R with geosphere

Tags: coordinate-system, r, distance

I am trying to compute the a distance matrix between two sets of points in two shapefiles (S1 and S2) in R. I am new to geographical analysis in R, having previously only used QGIS and ArcMap.

I am using to do so the packages geosphere and rgdal. My two shapefiles are in the projection  EPSG:102023. When I try to compute the distances using `distm`, I get the error:

```
 Error in .pointsToMatric(x): longitude <-360
```

Does this mean that you have to use Geographic coordinate systems to use  `distm`?

Here is my code:

> > proj4string(S1)
>
> [1] "+proj=eqdc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +x_0=0 +y_0=0
>   +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
>
> > head(coordinates(S1))
>
> ```
>   coords.x1 coords.x2
> ```
>
> [1,]  330091.20  -3277120
>
> [2,] -672066.99  -3753558
>
> [3,] -671040.65  -3755774
>
> [4,] -676182.43  -3741369
>
> [5,]   61188.02  -3759233
>
> [6,]  156078.69  -3687183
>
> > proj4string(S2)
>
> [1] "+proj=eqdc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +x_0=0 +y_0=0
>   +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
>
> > head(coordinates(S2))
>
> ```
>   coords.x1  coords.x2
> ```
>
> [1,] -1246820.3  -586142.4
>
> [2,]  1831068.8  1024375.2
>
> [3,] -1093944.1  -617261.2
>
> [4,] -1075037.3  -614924.2
>
> [5,]  -652579.9 -3745182.5
>
> [6,]  -498183.2   261947.4
>
> > test<-distm(coordinates(S1),coordinates(S2), fun=distHaversine)
>
> Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : longitude < -360

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing `coordinates(S1)` you are dropping the coordinate reference system and passing a simple matrix. `distm` then assumes you have lat-long and tries to do the calculation, but discovers your lat-long are huge values, outside the range of -360 to 360 (and -90 to +90) so you get that error.

If you pass the spatial objects themselves you get a different error:

```
> test<-distm(s1,s2, fun=distHaversine)
Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : 
  Points are projected. They should be in degrees (longitude/latitude)
```

which should make it clearer you need to `spTransform` to degrees lat-long before using `distm`.

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-5/topics/distm):

> **Arguments**:
>
> *x* longitude/latitude of point(s). Can be a vector of two numbers, a matrix of 2 columns (first one is longitude, second is latitude) or a
>   SpatialPoints* object
>
> *y* Same as x. If missing, y is the same as x

You need to use lat/long CRS. So:

```
library(sp)
S1b <- spTransform(S1, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
S2b <- spTransform(S2, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
test <- distm(coordinates(S1b),coordinates(S2b), fun=distHaversine)
```